# I have multiple select boxes inside foreach with the same name, and i want to call a showhide function with parameters

Tags: php

I have multiple select boxes inside a `foreach loop` with the same name,i want to call **showhide(nid,cid)** function and pass some parameters in `onchange` event

```php
@foreach($customers as $customer)
    @if($customer->customer)
    <tr id="row_{{$customer->customer_id}}">
        <td>{{ $customer->customer->email }}</td>
        <td>@if($customer->device){{ $platforms[$customer->device->platform] }}@endif</td>
        <td>{{ $customer->status }}</td>
        <td>{{ $customer->error }}</td>
        <td>
            <select name="hide" onchange="showhide($customer->notification_id,$customer->customer_id)">
                <option {{ $customer->hide ? 'selected':'' }} value="0">No</option>
                <option {{ $customer->hide ? 'selected':'' }}  value="1">Yes</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:resend({{$id}},{{ $customer->customer_id }})" title="Resend" ><i class="fa fa-send"></i>Resend</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

**javascript**

```
<script>
    function showhide(nid,cid)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",  
            url: '{{route("admin.notification.showhide")}}',
            data: "_token={{ csrf_token() }}&notification_id="+nid+"&customer_id="+cid,
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
                if(response.success==1){
                }
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
            } 
        });
    }
</script>

can anyone please help
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You need to give us an actual problem description, not just an “I want”. Explain what exactly you are struggling with here then.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the id of select box as the customer id, and pass this id parameter to a javascript  function.

```
  <a onclick="showhide('{{$customer->customer_id}}')"> </a>
```

and in the javascript function 
`function showhide(data)
{
$("#"+data).toggle();
}`